# Git wont ignore /build/intermediates/ files even though I added build/ to .gitignore

Tags: android, git, github

I am doing android development in android studio and i'm trying to ignore all /build/ files but it isn't working. This is my current .gitignore file

```
# built application files
*.apk
*.ap_

# files for the dex VM
*.dex

# Java class files
*.class

# built native files
*.o
*.so

# generated files
bin/
gen/

# Ignore gradle files
.gradle/
build/

# Local configuration file (sdk path, etc)
local.properties

# Proguard folder generated by Eclipse
proguard/

# Eclipse Metadata
.metadata/

# Mac OS X clutter
*.DS_Store

# Windows clutter
Thumbs.db

# Intellij IDEA (see https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/entries/23393067)
.idea/workspace.xml
.idea/tasks.xml
.idea/datasources.xml
.idea/dataSources.ids

.*
!/.gitignore
```

but when I do a git status, build files still appear

Comment: You need to add a .gitignore file to each module in your project

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Chances are they were added to the repo *before* they were added to the `.gitignore` file. You should remove them from the repo with `git rm --cached filename.ext`, and commit (along with the `.gitignore` file).

Comment: git rm --cached filename.ext didn't work. Am I supposed to replace "filename.ext" with something?

Comment: Yes, with the file(s) you actually want deleted/ignored. You can use wildcards, of course, so you do not have to do it for each individual file (hopefully!)

Comment: Actually, just do `git rm --cached buid/`, since it looks like that is the directory you are trying to ignore.

Comment: cool that worked. Thank you so much! Would you know how to ignore .iml files also?

Comment: `git rm --cached /actual_path/to/files/*.iml`.

Comment: No i mean, how would you actually ignore .iml files in .gitignore?

Comment: Oh, I see. Just add "*.iml" (without the quotes) to `.gitignore`.

Comment: I deleted the .git folder, re-added and the build/intermediates files are still present.